# matplotlib legend guide example using mpatches not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-3.4

Why does this example taken from [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html) and downloadable [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide-1.py) not work for me in Python 3:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='The red data')
plt.legend(handles=[red_patch])

plt.show()
```

I simply get a blank plot. My Python and matplotlib versions are 3.4.1 and 1.3.1, respectively.

I get this error code:

```
UserWarning: No labeled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on individual plots.
  warnings.warn("No labeled objects found. "
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue in Mac even now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the library like this for Python2:

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

and copy-pasted your example to a file and I got this image:

[image]

For **Python3** I just installed `python3-mathplotlib`:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

and I obtained the same image as above.

Comment: Thanks. It's probably some Mac issue then.